# How to modify the code of an Abstract class in Magento?

Tags: magento, overriding, abstract-class

In Magento, I want to modify the code of an Abstract class. Specifically, I want to modify the behavior of the function _getReadAdapter() of the class Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract.

According to this article by Alan Storm, http://alanstorm.com/magento_upgrade_rewrite_override, there are three ways to do it. Modifying the Magento's source code is very bad and not encouraged. On the other hand, it seems to me that I cannot use Magento's override/rewrite system, since the abstract class is neither a model, helper nor block. Is that correct?

As such, the only way to go about this is to make a copy of this particular source code at app/local/Mage, and modify the code of this new copy. Is that right?

Comment: Why do you want to modify `_getReadAdapter()` ?

Comment: I'm running a master-slave MySQL configuration. I want to allow code to set a flag that, from this point onwards until the flag is cleared, use WriteAdapter even when doing reading only. (Specifically, this search problem with master/slave configuration http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/216140/#t307279)

Comment: I don't think the problem should be handled like this. Your issue is with the lag between master and slave (data is replicated too slow)... have your sysadmin look at this.

Comment: Surely, the lag between master and slave can easily be caused by external networking problems that cannot be solved by software or configuration? (By the way, I'm forcing Magento to read from master only for the first time a particular search is made, since it is already writing to the Master to save the search result. Subsequent searches with the same search text will read from slave only.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, using the codepool `app/code/local` is the way to go.

This is because `abstract` classes are not handled by the Magento factories, but literally extended in the class definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should not modify abstract class, instead, you should modify the derive class that extends this abstract class

Comment: I want to have all present derived classes, and force all future derived classes, to inherit this new behavior.